Where is the server log for nextjs app runnning in azure static web apps?
I have successfully deploy a nextjs 14 app with azure static web apps. On some pages i get an server error:
> Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the
> server logs for more information).

Where can i find this information? I have activated app insight.

Can you share that how did you setup your app insight to the application.

@SureshChikkam Sorry, don´t know what you are asking for. I set "Enable Application Insights" to yes

As like this right?

@SureshChikkam Yes


Where can i find this information? I have activated app insight.

Once you get the application error or exception navigate to the application insight.


Go to Investigate<Transaction search<check the exception trace (error log trace).



Click on View to logs and follow the below query for the error log.

union isfuzzy=true
    exceptions,
    pageViews,
    traces,
    dependencies
| where timestamp > datetime("2024-04-09T10:13:28.407Z") and timestamp < datetime("2024-04-10T10:13:28.407Z")
| order by timestamp desc
| take 100

Exception logs:


Thanks that is good to know too. But it seems nextjs returns 200.  I think i need to see the result like using console.log("something") in a nodejs app. Where would i see this "something" information beeing logged?

Yes if you use like console.log("something") this. you can check the trace log as like this. There you can find the trace message in app insight.
